# Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Gallery not showing external storage images and videos?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

Prior to move my images and videos to External Storage via File Manager, I was still able to see them in Gallery, but not after I have moved all.

How to enable Gallery, to show my External Storage images and videos?

Comment: I am not sure how Gallery can be enabled but see if both apps mentioned [here can help](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160369/131553)

Comment: My bet is you need to rerun the [media-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) to update the corresponding database. Easiest way to achieve that is a simple reboot (for more details, follow the link). Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yes I have tried both of you guys suggested but nothing works..