# Why ES File Explorer not listed when I've to select file for web upload?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, browser, samsung-galaxy-tab, es-file-explorer

When using a Samsung Tab A, with Android 6, I would like to have **ES File Explorer** listed when I have to select a file to be upload from a web site file selector control.

Is there any configuration parameter that I'm missing to do that? Is it a permissions problem?

I have also have tried with other file explorers as AndSMB, and the same is happening... I only can select a file using the default android file explorer, the camera and the camcorder.

I'm trying to do something not allowed in ES File Explorer? Maybe I need another file explorer app to do that?

Comment: Look at the solution [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160369/131553)  which may help using either of  the two apps. I don't know why it happens but this solution send to work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do here? I can't understand what you're asking?

Comment: @MarkYisri If I got this right, OP wants to know why ES File Explorer doesn't appear in the list of providers that appear when one tries to upload a file somewhere. For reference, the list is the one that contains the **Internal Storage**, **External Storage**, **File Manager**, **Gallery**, ... entries. Maybe a screenshot from OP may help in clarifying this, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere - don't remember where anymore - that Google has made this impossible for 3rd party apps. Only system apps can be used by a browser to access data in storages. Try to install ES Explorer as system app (need root ) *(Will link my sources if I find them again)*

[image]