# Can not upload folder

Tags: backup

I'm trying to add folder in Degoo app for backup, but it is neither showing my sd card nor phone memory. It shows 'Recent' but in it nothing is there. How do I fix it.
This problem is not only with Degoo but I've faced it many times among various apps.

Device :: Lenovo K4 Vibe

Android :: 5.1 Lollipop

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Try the app picker classic app mentioned [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160369/131553)  all the best

Comment: App picker is not working. Nothing happened after installing.

Comment: Surprised. Did you reset the defaults? You can try the other app mentioned there also

Comment: The other app semi-fixed my problem, I can not select sd card but at least now I can select phone storage

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to say that the issue is related with the application or the phone, but it's obvious that Degoo servers are challenging with upload problems and receiving files which make many users to think it's a prank; also you should know that Degoo is a fully beta backup service with many bugs in coding, even without a web file manager. 
**I would stop using it as a serious backup cloud storage for my important files**, instead there are many tested storage services like Google Drive to be used; it's a fact that quality is not cheap or a speedy object.
If Degoo solves issues faster and prove itself as a huge cloud storage (not 100GB but more than 1TB for free) during next years it can be a successful innovation, but time matters.