# How to find a specific picture in Android's gallery app?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, gallery

I have some 1,500 photos on my smartphone taken over the course of more than a year.

In the Android default gallery app, the most recent pictures are shown on top, in a two-column layout.

**How can I directly jump to the oldest pictures, or to any of the pictures in between, without having to swipe some 30 times?**

Concrete issue: I am trying to select a photo, and the gallery app is launched in selection mode. Every once in a while (about once in 5 to 10 attempted swipes), when trying to swipe, I accidentally select a picture. I cannot undo that and return to the gallery app; instead I can only cancel the selection, re-open the gallery app, and start swiping from scratch.

Comment: @beeshyams: Indeed, default name. I only sort and rename photos after copying them to the desktop computer.

Comment: @beeshyams: Well, the photos are on the SD card. Tapping the two lines that indicate the total and available storage on the SD card has no effect.

Comment: @beeshyams: It shows up, but tapping it does not do anything. I can open the gallery via "internal storage" as you described (although that looks like it is just a more complicated way to open the gallery exactly the same way as from the applications menu), but in there, I do not see any sorting options.

Comment: @beeshyams: Sorry, it's Android 5.0.1 - added the appropriate tag.

Comment: @beeshyams: An alternative file explorer doesn't help me when a 3rd party app wants me to select a photo via the default gallery app.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear, for instance this aspect did not figure . Anyway, you can install *app picker classic* to *choose* file explorer as option to select a photo. See [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160369/131553)

Comment: With that app you can bypass default selection of your gallery app and instead choose a file explorer to be used by third party app