# How do I open a html file stored in Google Drive in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android, google-drive

Stuff I've already tried:

- Tried following the instructions given [here](http://www.howtodroid.com/2014/03/use-mobile-browser-local-files-android.html) but they do not work. I see the error **"Access to the file is denied"**.

*screenshot below*

[image: access denied error].

- Tried giving Firefox all possible permissions
- Tried opening the file in Chrome and then copy-pasting the url from the address bar to Firefox. This simply displays the "Open with" dialog and Firefox is not displayed in the list.
  [image: open with options]

Comment: You can try the solutions mentioned in this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160369/131553) to get over the problem of " opening with". Also try *Better open with* app on Play Store

Comment: [This add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-drive-files-search/?src=ss) let's you search your Google drive. Didn't fully try it but it is able see Google drive content when this is set to default search engine

Comment: @beeshyams thank you, but neither option worked.

Comment: What didn't work using the plug in option ? Seeing the drive? Or opening html file. I can see drive on FF 49.0.2