# Not able to open photos from "files" by swiping the screen.Need to open the photos one by one

Tags: photos, files, 7.0-nougat

I am not able to view the photos from "files" by swiping the screen.  Need to open the photos one by one.My Android version is Nougat.  Kindly help how I can view the photos by simply swiping the screen.

Comment: "Files" is a (simplified) file manager, not a gallery app. Don't you have a dedicated gallery app on the phone?

Comment: Hi am using file manager and ES File explorer , it is working fine in both the apps.But i was looking for the file app to be corrected as it is the default ap

Comment: So you mean the built-in "Files" is now your default picture viewing app? That shouldn't happen at all if you ask me...

Comment: Can you suggest a good app for picture viewing which is suitable for a normal user.I am facing some issues with both the apps i installed.

Comment: Well technically app recommendations are off-topic on this site, so out of respecting the rules I will not make explicit recommendations; however, just searching "Gallery" in Play Store would yield plenty of results for you to try out, some of them are tried-and-true as I heard from users I know.

Comment: Ok Thanks..So there is no option to rectify the viewing option in default app "Files"??.Before it was working fine but after i did default option selection, it stopped working.If it is asking one more time the default app option while opening photo from "Files", i think the issue will resolve.

Comment: So that's what you're asking about... Whatever you set as default, just go to Settings-Apps, find that app, and clear its default.

Comment: i cleared the default app for both Files and Gallery, still it is not asking for choosing the application while opening the pictures.Still the issue is present. I did a reset for settings , but no luck..

Comment: Weird... Upvoted for awareness, then. In the meantime, grab another gallery app. Hope others could make use of the info in our comments.

Comment: See of the app picker classic app mentioned [here helps](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160369/131553)